# Gitlab: can't force push after changing history (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I'm trying to remove a file from a projects commit history, I'm attempting this with the `git filter-repo` tool but I also got the same results when using `git filter-branch`, I'm able to successfully remove the file and rewrite the history locally but when I try to force push I get this error:

```
 ! [remote rejected]   develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I've tried a dry run before and it works well (`git push --force --verbose --dry-run`), also I understand git filter-repo removes the origin url, so this was after adding it back, git filter-branch does not remove the remote and I got the same results. Also tested on a newly created branch (just making sure it's not protected) with the same results

Note: I understand the dangers of pushing a rewritten history to the same repo, that's no concern in this particular case

Comment: The branch is most probably `protected`. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#configure-a-protected-branch. You can either unprotect the branch or ask the owner to promote your account to a role that is allowed to force push.

Comment: @ElpieKay, that was my first assumption but I have a maintainer role and I used the asterisk on the protected branches settings to make all branches pushable, or at least force pushable, but still getting the same

Comment: It's not a *Git* issue: the `pre-receive hook declined` message means it's due to the pre-receive code on the GitLab side. You'll have to investigate the GitLab settings more.